# Golang cobra CLI - get the currentl running subcommand

Tags: go, command-line-interface, go-cobra

Does cobra store the name of currently running sub-command somewhere? E.g. if user started the tool with commands like:

- tool sub-command -flag1 -flag2, etc.
- tool -globalflag1 sub-command -flag1 -flag2

is it possible to determine inside the program which sub-command is used from some variable or method?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the `Command.CalledAs` method? https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spf13/cobra#Command.CalledAs

Comment: Thanks, exactly! Alternative would be to do strings.Fields(cmd.CommandPath())[1], which I found out myself, but your method is much better.